# How to Get data from firestore with firestoreConnect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all the documents where `userId = idOwner`, but I create documents using `doc()` autogenerated

Is it possible to somehow get an array of data and pass it to a component and make `map()` ?
Or be sure to use `doc(userId)`

Now i get projects undefined

```js
let mapStateToProps = ({ firebase, firestore }) => {
  return {
    userId: firebase.auth.uid,
    projects: firestore.data.Projects,
    loading: firestore.status.requesting,
    fetched: firestore.status.requested
  };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect(props => [
    { collection: "Projects", where: [["idOwner", "==", props.userId]] }
  ])
)(dashBox);
```

Component

```js
                     take with userId ?
content = props.projects[props.userId].project.slice(0).map(p => (
      <div className={classes.projectsBox} key={p.id}>
        <NavLink to={"/project/" + p.id} className={classes.title}>
          {p.NameProj}
        </NavLink>
        <p className={classes.text}>{p.Text}</p>
        <div className={classes.bottom}>
          <p className={classes.date}>{p.startdate}</p>
          <p className={classes.date}>{p.enddate}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document has a single property called "projects", which is an array with a single maps element that has some properties.  However, Firestore doesn't offer the ability to query for documents whose array elements contain some property.  What you're trying to do is just not supported.

Instead of writing a document with an array type field, consider just writing all the objects fields to the top level of the document, so that you can target the idOwner property in a query.